# I got this error when pressing search button in home activity it should open search activity ! any idea please?

Tags: android, kotlin

```html
package com.app.mycare.screens.search

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.animation.Animation
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import android_mvvm.custom.ui.BaseActivity
import android_mvvm.mvvm.ViewModel
import com.app.mycare.R
import com.app.mycare.databinding.ActivitySearchBinding

class SearchActivity : BaseActivity(), SearchCallback {

    private var filtersShown = false

    override fun createViewModel(): ViewModel {
        return SearchViewModel(this)
    }

    override fun getLayoutId() = R.layout.activity_search

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val myBinding = this.binding as ActivitySearchBinding
        val filterSection = myBinding.searchFilterSection

        val slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up)
        slideUp.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener{
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {}
            override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {}
            override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
                filterSection.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        })

        val slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_down)
        slideDown.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener{
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {}
            override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
                filterSection.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {}
        })

        filterSection.visibility = View.GONE

        myBinding.searchFilter.setOnClickListener {
            if(filtersShown) {
                //myBinding.searchFilterSection.startAnimation(slideUp)
                filterSection.visibility = View.GONE
                filtersShown = false
            } else {
                filterSection.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                myBinding.searchFilterSection.startAnimation(slideDown)
                filtersShown = true
            }
        }
    }

    override fun hideFilters() {
        if(filtersShown){
            (this.binding as ActivitySearchBinding).searchFilter.performClick()
        }
    }
}

interface SearchCallback{
    fun hideFilters()
}
```

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.mycare, PID: 7838
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.mycare/com.app.mycare.screens.search.SearchActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property resources has not been initialized
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property resources has not been initialized
at android_mvvm.mvvm.ViewModel.getResources(ViewModel.kt:18)
at com.app.mycare.screens.search.SearchViewModel.(SearchViewModel.kt:27)
at com.app.mycare.screens.search.SearchActivity.createViewModel(SearchActivity.kt:17)
at android_mvvm.mvvm.MvvmActivity.onCreate(MvvmActivity.java:42)
at android_mvvm.custom.ui.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:33)
at com.app.mycare.screens.search.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.kt:23)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)

Comment: Well the logs say this: `lateinit property resources has not been initialized`, So somewhere in your activity you have a lateinit var that you aren't setting and it tries accessing it which causes the crash - would need to see the activity code to know exactly what that var is

Comment: Looks like `SearchActivity.kt line 23` would be a good place to look

Comment: i put the activity search code but in the line 23 is the super.oncreate

Comment: @Quinn do you know where is the problem ?

Comment: I think you should look into this ```com.app.mycare.screens.search.SearchViewModel.(SearchViewModel.kt:27)``` and ```com.app.mycare.screens.search.SearchActivity.createViewModel(SearchActivity.kt:17)```

Comment: @Quinn       private val none = resources.getString(R.string.search_option_none)

Comment: @PrinceAli what do you think ?

Comment: @VonC can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `onCreate` is calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`, which is the `onCreate` in `BaseActivity`. *That* is calling the `onCreate` in `MvvmActivity` (I'm guessing it's `BaseActivity`'s superclass), and **that** is calling `createViewModel` in `SearchActivity` (I'm reading the stacktrace bottom-up here, btw)

The constructor / init for `SearchViewModel` is calling `getResources()` on some `ViewModel` (some property in the superclass maybe?) - and that hasn't been initialised yet, which is why you're getting a crash.

I'm not familiar with the `android_mvvm` library you're using, so that's all I can tell you! Look into what you're supposed to do to initialise things in those `ViewModel` classes it provides